# How to make delicious homemade ice cream

Tags: particles, physics, fluid-simulation, soft-body

I am working on a project for a client in which I need to make a short gif animation for a series of icons. One of these is an ice cream cone and for its animation I'd like to have a cone spin into frame, and then have a big scoop of ice cream plop onto it. I can **not** figure out how to make a simulated material that behaves like ice cream! I'm going for semi-realism here, and I want the 'plop' to be visually satisfying, but I don't know if I should be using a soft body, particles, fluid, etc.

I've tried all and can't quite get the interaction to look right. Has anyone done a physics sim with a ice-cream/paste like substance? What were your settings? I'm way overdue on this project and I'm about to settle on a look that I'm not happy with.

Comment: Could you share your closest attempt and an explanation of what did and didn't work?

Comment: I would try fluid + viscosity

Comment: How long is the .gif? How big is the .gif? The answers to those may determine how lazy you can be  :)

Answer (score 6):

As Chris says the most realistic would probably be to use fluid with viscosity.

A less realistic solution would be to create a spiral curve and give it a *Geometry > Bevel > Object* so that it follows the profile you want, with a *Taper* object to make it thinner or thicker all along. Then enable *Map Taper* and animate the *Start & End Mapping* values. You can also create some shape keys if you want to move a bit, it can also be done with *Hook* modifiers:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Aaaah …moonboots - now I am hungry…. +1

Comment: be careful, don't eat polygons!!

Comment: What happens if I …

Comment: intestinal perforation   :((  unless you've subdivided enough

Comment: Awesome! XD. Just run the animation to the end, and you'll be able to drink it.

Comment: Yes I forgot to say, keep a low Strength value for the  Sun if you don't want your ice cream to liquify

Comment: i think this is worth a downvote to forget that....but since i am afraid of your laser eyes...i keep the upvote....

Comment: maybe you should model a refrigerator right beneath it...so we won't loose it

Comment: sure, your right, my team is working on it

Comment: so your team is your brain and your hands....or more...? :D

Comment: I have a full company completely dedicated to BlenderStackExchange questions here