# Is there a way to make the liquid stick to a mesh ? Instead of sliding off

Tags: fluid-simulation, mantaflow

I'm trying to animate a chocolate pouring on top of an ice cream which is rotating and moving. I tried all sorts of settings on the liquid mesh but every time the ice cream makes the slightest move, the liquid just slides off like it has no stickiness at all, the hydrophobic behaviour is very high so to speak. Now there is an option under viscosity (Surface Tension) which is suppose to control exactly the hydrophobic property of a liquid, but I tried it at all sorts of values and didn't see any difference whatsoever... What am I missing here ?

Settings:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I parented the domain to the cone because if you scale up the domain, the simulation doesn't work...

The problem:
The topping just slides off every time the cone makes slightest movement

[image]

I played with some settings and got it to look like this at some point which is somehow keeping it together but I don't know how I achieved that because I wanted a better result and I messed up again... I cannot go back to the same settings:

[image]

Comment: what strength for viscosity did you use? without seeing any of your settings we can just guess around...so please improve your question and show us all of your fluid settings (domain, effector and geometry/inflow)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/187019/piping-cream-through-a-piping-tip https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48669/how-can-i-make-a-fluid-simulation-liquid-become-gooey-or-viscous https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/240517/how-to-make-delicious-homemade-ice-cream/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45374/how-can-i-model-ultra-viscous-dripping-wet-objects https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/79683/simulate-a-sticky-fluid-in-blender https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/125023/how-can-i-model-something-that-behaves-like-molasses/125041#125041

Comment: Please show your Blender scene  as a Blender screen capture.  Some questions which could be answered by a clear screen capture (.png).  Which fluid simulation solver? Blender?  If not Blender can you copy and paste the text describing viscosity.  Blender native fluid simulation has two viscosity settings.  Neither of them use the word hydrophobic, but rather force is the concern.